# For loop over 'NoneType' TensorFlow Dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I'm implementing a new type of NN in TensorFlow. The difference is in the evaluation function, so instead of calling `tf.matmul()`, I call my own function, which we'll call `My_Function(A)`.

A snippet of the code can be seen below, where `A` is the tensor on the left being multiplied by this new NN implementation, which is on the right. The equivalent tensorflow code would be `tf.matmul(A, this_new_NN)`.

```
def My_Function(self, A):
    dims = A.get_shape().as_list()
    shape = [dims[0], self.m] # Defining shape of resulting tensor
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[shape[0], shape[1]])
    result = tf.zeros(tf.shape(X), dtype=tf.float32)
    for xyz in self.property:
        # Do some computation between A and xyz, xyz is a property of this_new_NN
        # resulting to temp_H with dimension [shape[0], xyz.m] of type tf.tensor
        dims_H = temp_H.get_shape().as_list()
        indices = [[i,j] for i in range(0, dims_H[0]) for j in range(xyz.k, xyz.k+dims_H[1])]
        # indices is a list of indices to update in "result"
        values = tf.reshape(temp_H, [-1]) # Values in temp_H as 1D list
        delta = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape)
        result += tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(delta)
    return result
```

Now the problem I'm having is in the line where I calculate the `indices`, where I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Now, I understand that this error means that you cannot iterate a for loop over a type of `None`, but the problem I have is the test set and the training set have different values for `batch_size`. This means that when I go to create `result`, the first dimension is unknown which is why it is of type `None`.

But, to get the indices that I have to update in `result`, I have to use a for loop to generate those values as a list to feed into `delta` which I'm creating as a `tf.SparseTensor` so it can be added to `result`.

My question is, what is the best way to get the indices? I have tried replacing `dims_H[0]` in the for loop with a `tf.placeholder(tf.int32)` object instead, where I would then just pass the size when I run the session, but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

**Edit:**

Just for reference, this code is called in the following way, where `M` is the pre-built new NN composed with `tf.Variable` values.

```
Y1 = tf.nn.relu(M.My_Function(A) + B1)
```

where `B1` is the offset for this layer, and `A` is the input layer.

**Edit2:**

`result` should be a zero tensor *every time* `My_Function` is called. However, I have a suspicion that it is preserving the values of `result` with each function call. If this is right, please let me know what I need to do to change that.

**Edit3:**

When defining `A` it is defined as

```
X1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
A = tf.reshape(X1, [-1, 28*28])
```

As the dimensions of `A` change between the training data and test data.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this

```
>>> range(None, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    range(None, 0)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Check if `xyz.k` is not `None`.

Comment: It's not. When the dimensions of `A` are fixed my code functions perfectly. However, when the dimensions are fixed I cannot run it on the test and training data.

Comment: The problem stems from `dim_H[0]` being `None`, which this value comes from `shape[0]`, which is the first dimension of `A`, which is of type `None`. 

I have added another edit to show how `A` is created.